# How can I trust in 'lock' anymore?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

back on my old unmanaged c++ days, I could trust in my critical sections in a multithreading application. So, now with dotNet/C#, I was relaying on the lock mechanism. By locking a resource I was confident any thread couldn't access those resources within my piece of code.

This seems not to be true in dotNet!

I have my windows service application. I create a main managed thread with an hidden Form hosting a third parity OCX. Within this thread I do message pumping an polling on a list of objects. This list of objects gets modified by events fired by the OCX within this managed thread.

I post simplified parts of my code here:

```
  public bool Start()
  {
     ServiceIsRunning = true;

     m_TaskThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(TaskLoop));
     m_TaskThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
     m_TaskThread.Start(this);

     return true;
  }

  private void OnOCXEvent(object objToAdd)
  {
     lock(m_ObjectList)
     {
        m_ObjectList.Add(objToAdd);            }
     }
  }

  private void CheckList()
  {
     lock(m_ObjectList)
     {
        foreach(object obj in m_ObjectList)
        {
           ...
        }
     }
  }

  [STAThread] // OCX requirement!
  private void TaskLoop(object startParam)
  {
     try {

        ... 

        while (ServiceIsRunning)
        {
           // Message pump 
           Application.DoEvents();

           if (checkTimeout.IsElapsed(true))
           {
              CheckList();
           }

           // Relax process CPU time!
           Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
     } catch(Exception ex) {
        ... 
     }
  }
```

You won't beleve me: I got a 'list has been modified'  exception in CheckList! 8-/

So I did some logging and I noticed that the OnOCXEvent will be raised when the **SAME** managed thread is within the CheckList foreach loop. I'm sure: I got the same managed thread id in my log file, the foreach loop wasn't finished and the OnOCXEvent has been called by the same manged thread!

Now I'm wondering: how can this happen? Is a single managed thread implemented with more win32 threads?

Hope someone can explain why this is happening, so I can solve this issue.

Thanks, 
Fabio

### My Note:

I actually solved the issue creating a copy of the list before the foreach loop. But I do not like this solution. I also like to understand what is happening. I do not own the third parity OCX code, but the method I call within the CheckList loop has logically nothing to do with the OCX event beening fired.

Comment: What does your `CheckList` method do in the foreach loop? Does it call `Application.DoEvents` anywhere, or anything similar?

Comment: Can you post the code inside `CheckList()`?

Comment: You should first suspect yourself rather than suspecting the framework.

Comment: within CheckList() I'm calling a OCX object method, but this is not the cause of the OnOCXEvent event firing.

Comment: @Cabbi: Are you *sure*? Are you sure that OCX method doesn't pump the STA thread, for example - potentially raising the event? That seems the most likely approach.

Comment: sorry, I corrected my code, within the foreach I have m_ObjectList

Comment: Note what it says on MSDN: "...if your thread is in a single-threaded apartment, all these managed blocking operations will correctly pump messages in your apartment while your thread is blocked." - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74169f59.aspx

Comment: I'm NOT saying the framework is doing wrong: I'm saying tha I do not trust in my knowladge of single managed thread.

Comment: _logically nothing to do with the OCX event_  logical independence might not be enough here. Any OCX method might behave as DoEvents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I strongly suspect this is just a re-entrancy issue.

Within your `CheckList` call you're calling an OCX method. If that does *anything* which can itself raise OCX events - including effectively calling `Application.DoEvents` - then you can end up with `OnOCXEvent` being called in a thread which is *also* executing `CheckList`... and that will cause the problem.

This isn't an issue with `lock` - it's an issue with re-entrancy.

One way to diagnose this would be to modify your `CheckList` and `OnOCXEvent` methods:

```
private bool inCheckList;

private void OnOCXEvent(object objToAdd)
{
   lock(m_ObjectList)
   {
      if (inCheckList)
      {
         throw new Exception("Look at this stack trace!");
      }
      m_ObjectList.Add(objToAdd);
   }
}

private void CheckList()
{
   lock(m_ObjectList)
   {
      inCheckList = true;
      foreach(object obj in m_ObjectList)
      {
         ...
      }
      inCheckList = false; // Put this in a finally block if you really want
   }
}
```

I strongly suspect you'll see the exception thrown with a stack trace which includes `CheckList`, `OnOCXEvent` - and a bunch of code in-between, with something that runs the message loop in the middle.

Comment: I'm sure I'll see your're throw new Exception("Look at this stack trace!"). This is actually exactly what is happening. I also know that 'lock' will only lock different threads. So tha's why I'm surprised.

Comment: @Cabbi: No, that's why you *shouldn't* be surprised - and shouldn't be blaming `lock` at all. You've got re-entrancy in a single thread, so `lock` is simply an inappropriate tool for the job. A non-reentrant lock wouldn't help you either - you'd just get a single thread deadlocking itself.

Comment: Yup 'Application.DoEvents();' again.

Comment: @MartinJames: Possibly, but not the `Application.DoEvents` call shown here - I wouldn't expect *that* one to be the culprit (although I originally did - see this answer's edit history).